# How to extract data from a process instance using instance ID

Tags: business-process-management, ibm-bpm

I am trying to extract data from IBM BPM using the REST API.I am using the process instance ID to perform the search. However only one column is needed but it returns several and wanted to know of any recommendations that I can use to edit the search as I am going to do this for 3000+ processes

so far I have tried wle/v1/process?action=getdetails&instanceIds=11162090&parts=data

wle/v1/process?action=getdetails&instanceIds=11162090&parts=data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only provided functionality for reducing the payload when you make this call is the "parts" argument you have already provided.  Data is likely the one you want.  If what you want is something that is common to every single process instance no matter how it was implemented (e.g. start date, or due date) then you can query the lsw_bpd_instance table on the database that uses jdbc/Teamworks as its jndi entry.  There you can pull whatever you want.

More details about the problem you are attempting to solve might allow us to provide some other options.

Note - the API call you reference will take a comma separated list of instance id's if you want to get several returned at once.

-Andrew Paier